# wordpress: optimize way to writing to update_user_meta() function

Tags: wordpress

Currently using below lines to update/insert user data in wordpress table:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'promos', $promos );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'oil', $oil );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'statealert', $statealert );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'reminder', $reminder );
```

Wondering if I could achieve this in single line
Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's no `update_user_metaS`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1124). But it's easy to do it if you store everything as an array, so you can use a single `get()` and a single `update()`:

```
update_user_meta( 
    $user_id, 
    'my_array_user_meta', 
    array( 
        'promos'     => $promos, 
        'oil'        => $oil, 
        'statealert' => $statealert, 
        'reminder'   => $reminder 
    ) 
);
```